# Is there an API for UK Clean Air Zones?

Tags: openstreetmap

According to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dlow_emission_zone#United_Kingdom there are now 13 clean air or similar zones in the UK.

What I am hoping to do is feed an API a lat/lng and it return whether or not it is included inside one of these zones, and if so which one(s). Obviously the data needs to be kept updated for new/expanded LEZs.

I've done the usual Google searches and searched the dev docs on Google Maps API and others, but can't see a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If the rate at which the API will be queried is compatible with overpass, you could directly query it.

```
out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “boundary=low_emission_zone”
  node["boundary"="low_emission_zone"]({{bbox}});
  way["boundary"="low_emission_zone"]({{bbox}});
  relation["boundary"="low_emission_zone"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Substitute {{bbox}} with your bounding box coordinates, for instance `(51.39043617324214,-2.37504243850708,51.3949617027702,-2.3631334304809566)`

Otherwise you would need to preload the list of clean air zones and check if the input coordinates are in one of them.
This query loads all the zones for England

```
[out:json][timeout:25]; // gather results

( area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="GB"];) ->.gb;  relation["boundary"="low_emission_zone"](area.gb);

// print results out body;
>; out skel qt;
```

There is probably a way to improve the overpass query to reduce the output.